# Is there a range('a','z') for Non-English Alphabet

Tags: php, string, nlp

PHP has a function `range('a','z')` which prints the English alphabet a, b, c, d, etc.

Is there a similar function for other alphabets? maybe a function that accepts the language as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = range('а', 'я');

var_dump($arr);
```

But this will work with `cp1251` only and lost `ё`, since it is in the end of the ascii table

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. PHP isn't aware of Unicode or similar.

Also, `range()` doesn't print, it returns an array. To print it, you'd do `echo implode(range('a', 'z'))`.

Comment: really? they haven't fixed that yet?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Range a-z probably creates an array and returns it. I could create a similar function for my language of choice, but don't want to if it's already available.

Comment: @Ralph Nup. Apparently in PHP6 they will support Unicode, but that will probably be out in 2030 :P

Comment: @jblue `range('a','z')` *does* return an array. If you are using non ASCII chars, you will need to create your own version of `range()`.

Answer (score 1):

Alphabetical sequences in Unicode do not follow English alpha order. You'll have to construct the string yourself. Consider defining it as a global constant